# Create a Raster from non-rectangular XYZ data in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have some X Y Z data that I have loaded into a layer in QGIS using the 'Add Deliminated text Layer'

I get all the data in, unfortunately it is a non-rectangular region.  I would like to generate a surface map of the data, but unfortunately, when I do it, it generates everything over a large rectangle, and not just over the extents of where I have data.
[image: MBES Data]

When I generate the interpolation using 'TIN Interpolation' I get the following output.

[image]

My parameters for creating the rasters are as below.
[image]

The raw data is available here
[Download Data](https://login.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6b69895e61767aa6aa)

Comment: Rasters have fixed dimensions (width and height) and every pixel exists and has some value. What would you expect?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to clip the raster to only where I have data.

Comment: Rasters are like a chessboard and you have the squares even where you do not have pieces or pawns. Depending on your use case you may limit the total size of DEM data by creating a set of smaller files which overlap a bit and follow closer the area where you have data. Then your software must be able to handle a mosaic of small DEM files.

Comment: Is there any other way, instead of creating a raster, that would allow me to create a seabed elevation surface?